# RoR Active Record unknown attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting an ActiveRecord error after submitting a form for a table called worequests.  The error is "unknown attribute: contact_id".  But, the worequests table contains contact_id.  It is a foreign key to the contacts table.  In my worequest model, I have "belongs_to :contact" and in my contact model, I have "has_many :worequests".

Comment: Have you reset up the db....rake db:reset && rake db:migrate

did you create the contact_id through a migration or when you setup the model?

Can you access data in the rails console?

Include your model files and the offending view source to help us.

Comment: I fixed the problem.  When I create a worequest, I also have code to  create a record in a comment table.  The code is in the worequest model.  In that line of code I had a field typed wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. When I create a worequest, I also have code to create a record in a comment table. The code is in the worequest model. In that line of code I had a field typed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran your migrations?
After adding the relationship you need to add references to your schema.